# Trigger Fargate to process file uploaded to S3

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am trying to get a CDK application to setup a Fargate task that will automatically process files uploaded to an S3 bucket.

I have a rule target:

```
rule_target = targets.EcsTask(
    cluster=cluster,
    task_definition=task_definition,
    task_count=1
)
```

And I have a rule:

```
s3_upload_rule = events.Rule(
    self,
    's3_upload_rule',
    event_pattern=trigger_event_pattern,
    rule_name='s3_upload_rule',
    targets=[rule_target]
)
```

There is a lot of other stuff of course, but as far as I can see, the solution must be here. If I were to list everything, this would be a long post. The rule works and the Fargate task is executed, but it doesn't get any input.

My initial assumption would be to use container_overrides just like with a regular run_task, but since it only accepts strings, it would be difficult to tell it that I want the event or parts of the event.

Other events targets take RuleTargetInput parameters which solves this, however, EcsTask does not.

The documentation of Rule says:

> targets (Optional[List[IRuleTarget]]) – Targets to invoke when this rule matches an event. Input will be the full matched event. If you wish to specify custom target input, use addTarget(target[, inputOptions]). Default: - No targets.

If I try to do that, I get *TypeError: add_target() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given* so the documentation doesn't seem to be correct.

I have also tried creating a RuleTargetConfig with input specification, but I haven't found a way of connecting it to either the rule or the rule target (EcsTask). EcsTask doesn't have any ARN.

Connecting the rule_target to the rule with bind was tempting since it returns a RuleTargetConfig, but the input parameter is read only so that is also a dead end.

I know this is simple to do with lambda and that the lambda handler gets the full event by default, but I need to do heavy processing that will sometimes cause the lambda function to time out. There is of course the possibility of triggering a lambda that will run the Fargate task. This will solve my problem, but then I will keep trying to solve this without lambda anyway since it seems that it must be doable without lambda. Why else would there be a possibility of triggering EcsTasks from EventBridge.

Comment: It looks like you have to use an [InputTransformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/transform-input.html) to build the container overrides. I haven't done this myself, but I found an [example blog post](https://medium.com/@piyalikamra/s3-event-based-trigger-mechanism-to-start-ecs-far-gate-tasks-without-lambda-32f57ed10b0d).

Comment: What I have done before was to trigger a lambda that starts a step function. The step function did some processing, and then triggered the fargate task. Works well and gives you some extra visibility and control.

Comment: I looked at the InputTransformer approach. It does not seem to be supported in CDK, at least for EcsTask.

Comment: I will probably end up with a lambda to trigger the processing. I will probably chain lambda functions triggering on S3 since stepfunctions don't support SageMaker inference.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering Fargate through EventBridge should work.

This CDK code should do the trick.

```
events.Rule(
    self,
    bucket_name,
    event_bus=event_bus,
    event_pattern=events.EventPattern(detail_type=['Object Created']),
    targets=[targets.EcsTask(cluster, task_definition, task_definition.task_role)]
)
```

In order for this to work, you currently have to go to the **Properties** tab of the S3 bucket in the console and set **Amazon EventBridge** to **On**. I have not found a way to do this with CDK.

Comment: Is this still the case? I believe you should be able to do it as highlighted in this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html However Im unsure how to include it in CDK which is what I'm looking for at the moment. Lemme know if you ended up finding a solution, cheers

Comment: You are right, @mrammah. I have updated my answer to reflect this. We are using EventBridge notifications to start Step Functions so this approach works.